# When I install React Router on Create React App it deletes 1008 modules

Tags: reactjs

SO I npm installl react-router for create-react-app and when it finish is says created 18 and deleted 1008 modules. Now when I npm start the existing create-react-app app it says "react-scripts: command not found" and sure enough all of the files under react-scripts are deleted so now I can't start my project. What am I missing here? Why is the basic install deleting all of my modules?

Comment: `npm install react-router`  will not delete the exist package.  Could you run `history` command and paste the list which command you executed.

Comment: I will walk you through exactly what I did. I navigated via cd to the create-react-app project I am working in. I cd into that project and once there run npm install react-router --save. Then at the end it says exactly this "added 6 packages, removed 1124 packages and updated 19 packages in 11.088s"

Comment: Could you paste  `package.json` file which at create-react-app root path?

Comment: {
  "name": "my-abc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}

Comment: This is the path the package.json:  my-app/package.json

Comment: sorry. I can't reproduce your problem. you can delete `my-app/node_modules` dir and  `my-app/package-lock.json` then reinstall the package.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the src files and then delete your current project.
Then create a new react app.
Then instead of `npm install react-router-dom`

use `yarn add react-router-dom`

that should be able to Resolving packages and link dependencies.